# Javascript match and highlight advanced

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a search engine with javascript and PHP. So far, I have had success, but I still have a bit problem with highlighting search terms and limiting the words. The backend response is returning a JSON with a title and description, and the description could be long, so I want to limit the text and highlight those words that the user is searching for.

So basically, if backend response is like:

```
[{
    "title": "Test topic",
    "description": "<p>This topic contains some words that user is searching for</p> 
    <div><h1>It could contain anything</h1>
    <p> It could contain anything. Important thing is that it should work.</p>
    <img src="some_pic.jpg/>"
   }]
```

So, if I'm searching for something like "What important topic contains". The user should see a parsed version of the description (or whatever string given), with limiting the text radius around the search term. And for this, perfect response would be like:

> This **topic contains** some words that user... It could **contain**
> anything. **Important** thing is that it would...

So I didn't pay attention to the details here in words, to be exact with the radius, but I think you got the idea.

So what I did so far is

- map the response from the backend
- delete html code (in order to prevent ex. "...ong>") `
- split the search term words and execute the function to find them, make them bold and make a radius around them
- show to the user in a view

***Where is the problem?*** I have no logic to match 2 words, I'm splitting search term, creating an array and pushing parsed version into that array.

And it looks like: (important part of the component)

```
{
  searchResults.length > 0 ? (
    <div>
      <span className={`text-xs text-blue`}>Threads</span>
      {searchResults?.map((searched: any, index: Key) => {
        // Replace html code (just in case)
        const searchTerm = searched.description.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, " ");

        // Create array to push search term
        const searchArray: any[] = [];

        // Split search words into array and match results separately
        search.split(" ").map((text, i) => {
          // This function will be in the next code
          searchArray.push(searchText(searchTerm, text));
        });

        // Just a view here
        return (
          <Link key={index} href={"/forum/thread/" + searched?.slug}>
            <article
              className={`w-full bg-gray-dark  mb-2 px-3 py-1.5 rounded-xl text-gray-light`}
            >
              <h2>{searched.title}</h2>
              {searchArray.map((match, i) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    {/*Just in case, show it as html*/}
                    <div
                      className={`quill post-content text-xs text-gray`}
                      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: match }}
                    />
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </article>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```

And finally, a logic to highlight the text and make a radius around that word.

```
const searchText = (description: string, search: string) => {
        const radius = 30;
        const indexPosition = description.search(search)
        const startPosition = indexPosition - radius < 0 ? indexPosition : indexPosition - radius
        const endPosition = indexPosition + radius + search.length

        return (`...${description.slice(startPosition, endPosition)}...`).replace(search, `<span class="font-bold text-yellow">${search}</span>`)
    }
```

So in all that case I would see at the end (with same search term "What important topic contains")

> ...anything. **Important** thing is that it would...
> ...This **topic** contains some words that...
> ...This topic **contains** some words that user...
> ... It could **contain** anything. Important thing...

Basically searching every word couple of times. Any ideas how to improve that logic?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-pass solution. It works as follows:

0. Setup

   - Initialize an array of `fencepostPairs` (`[start: number, end: number]`), to track where each span starts and ends
   - Combine search terms into a dynamically-created regex `termsRe`
   - Sanitize description
1. First pass

   - Iterate over all matches of `termsRe` against the sanitized description, expanding each into a span of text depending on the configured "radius", truncating at the start and end of the sanitized description's length
   - For each span, check if it overlaps an existing pair of fenceposts (only need to check in backwards direction, as the regex matches in order of placement within the string). If it overlaps, replace the overlapping pair with the expanded range; if not, append the new pair
2. Second pass

   - Map the fencepost pairs to their respective text spans, adding HTML to highlight the matches within each span, using `termsRe`
   - Join the spans with line breaks

```js
const NON_WORD_CHARS = /[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]+/u
const ELIPSIS = '…'
const RADIUS = 30

const formatDescription = (description, search) => {
    const fencepostPairs = []
    
    // not technically necessary given we split on all non-word chars, but it'd be necessary if
    // e.g. we wanted to include "$" as a word char
    const regexEscape = (x) => x.replaceAll(/[\x00-\x7f]/g, m => /\W/.test(m) ? '\\x' + m.codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, '0') : m)
        
    // sort by length descending to ensure longer matches are preferred over shorter ones
    const terms = search.split(NON_WORD_CHARS).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
    
    // lookahead (?=...) and lookbehind (?<=...) groups to ensure only full words matched
    const termsRe = new RegExp(`(?<=${NON_WORD_CHARS.source}|^)(${terms.map(regexEscape).join('|')})(?=${NON_WORD_CHARS.source}|$)`, 'giu')
    
    const sanitized = description.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
    
    for (const { 0: match, index } of sanitized.matchAll(termsRe)) {
        const start = Math.max(0, index - RADIUS)
        const end = Math.min(sanitized.length, index + match.length + RADIUS)
        
        const overlapIdx = fencepostPairs.findIndex(([s, e]) => e >= start)
        
        if (overlapIdx === -1) {
            fencepostPairs.push([start, end])
        } else {
            const candidates = [start, end, ...fencepostPairs[overlapIdx]]
            
            fencepostPairs[overlapIdx] = [Math.min(...candidates), Math.max(...candidates)]
        }
    }
    
    const getFragment = ([start, end]) => {
        const fragment = sanitized.slice(start, end)
        
        return [
            start && ELIPSIS,
            fragment.replaceAll(termsRe, '<em class="highlight">$&</em>'),
            end !== sanitized.length && ELIPSIS,
        ].filter(Boolean).join('')
    }
    
    const fragments = fencepostPairs.map(getFragment)
    return fragments.join('<br>')
}

const search = 'What other important topic contains'

const description = `<p>Important: This topic contains some words that user is searching for</p> 
<div><h1>It could contain anything</h1>
<p> It could contain anything. The important thing is that it should work.</p>
<img src="some_pic.jpg">

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

<p>Here is some more text about another topic, which contains some more words that user is searching for.</p> 
<p>It is also important.</p>`

document.querySelector('#target').innerHTML = formatDescription(description, search)
```

```css
#target {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.highlight {
    font-style: normal;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```